# Parametrizando DataSet em C#

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, ado.net, dataset

Criei uma tela de busca com uma `textbox`, um `button` e uma `gridview`.
Gostaria que os resultados da pesquisa aparecessem nesta `Gridview` mas só consigo fazer isso com um `Dataset`. Neste caso precisava achar um jeito de passar parâmetros através desta `DataSet`.

Segue o código para avaliação:

```
protected void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pesquisa = txtBusca.Text.Trim();
    CarrinhoCompraBD bd = new CarrinhoCompraBD();
    CarrinhoCompras select = bd.Select(pesquisa);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = bd.Select(); //Esta linha é onde o visual studio aponda o erro
    lblTeste.Text = "Resultado da busca para: " + CarregaResultado(pesquisa) +".";
    gvResultado.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; //CarregaResultado(pesquisa);
    gvResultado.DataBind();
}
protected string CarregaResultado(string pesquisa)
{
    CarrinhoCompraBD bd = new CarrinhoCompraBD();
    CarrinhoCompras select = new CarrinhoCompras();
    select = bd.Select(pesquisa);

    gvResultado.Visible = true;
    pesquisa = select.Busca;
    return pesquisa;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não entendi porque você separou o procedimento em dois métodos. De qualquer forma, o erro não parece ser do *binding* do `DataSet` com a `GridView`, e sim com o método `Select`.

Seu código pode ser simplificado para:

```
protected void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pesquisa = txtBusca.Text.Trim();
    CarrinhoCompraBD bd = new CarrinhoCompraBD();
    CarrinhoCompras select = bd.Select(pesquisa);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // ds = bd.Select(); //Esta linha é onde o visual studio aponda o erro
    gvResultado.Visible = true;
    lblTeste.Text = "Resultado da busca para: " + select.Busca +".";
    gvResultado.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; //CarregaResultado(pesquisa);
    gvResultado.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Olá Morrison, tudo bem?
Olha só, desculpe a demora pra responder. Então, esse é um trabalho pra faculdade mas eu já havia resolvido só que não tive tempo pra postar aqui. Sua dica pra encurtar o código tbm funcionou, testei posteriormente mas não resolvia o problema pois o erro estava em outra classe.

Mesmo assim meu muito obrigado pela atenção
Desculpe pelo erro, sou iniciante nisso, muito a aprender ainda

Comment: Tranquilidade. Precisando, estamos aí.